# Wrote a bash code for UNIX to act as recyclebin. Stuck at passing argument to test function

Tags: linux, unix, recycle-bin

I wrote a code for recyclebin file for UNIX. And when i bash recyclebin -i filename,
it reads the getopts passed before the filename and after that it calls test function
and enter into the test function but doesnt enter the for loop inside the function. The program is not going anywhere from there, i am stuck there. Any help what am i doing wrong there

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
#!bin/bash

### 2. creating directory ~/recyclebin in home if not present
if [[ ! -d $HOME/recyclebin ]]
then
        mkdir $HOME/recyclebin
        #touch $HOME/.restore.info
fi

if [ -d $HOME/recyclebin ] && [ ! -e $HOME/.restore.info ]
then
        touch $HOME/.restore.info
fi

### 4. Test Conditions

function test() {
        for arg in $*
                do

                file=$arg

                ###No Filename Provided Error
                if [ $# -eq 0 ]
                then
                        echo "missing operand"
                        file="Error"
                        exit 1

                ###File Does Not Exist Error
                elif [ ! -e $file ]
                then
                        echo "Cannot delete $file: No such file exists"
                        file="Error"
                        exit 2

                ###Directory Name provided
                elif [ -d $file ]
                then
                        echo "Cannot delete $file : Not a file."
                        file="Error"
                        exit 3

                ###cannot delete any argument with recycle in it
                elif [[ "${file}" =~ .*"recycle".* ]]
                then
                        echo "Attempting to delete recycle – operation aborted"
                        file="Error"
                        exit 4
                fi

                processRequest
                done
}

processRequest(){
echo "Entered processRequest"
        if [ $noChoice = true ]
        then
                recycle

        elif [ $iOption = true ] && [ $vOption = true ]
        then
                read -p "recycle: remove file '$file' ? [y/n] " response

                case $response in
                        [yY]*)
                                recycle
                                echo "recycle: '$file' is removed";;
                        *)
                                continue ;;
                esac

        elif [ $iOption = true ]
        then
                read -p "recycle: remove file '$file' ? [y/n] " response

                case $response in
                        [yY]*)
                                recycle
                                echo "recycle: '$file' is removed";;
                        *)
                                continue ;;
                esac

        elif [ $vOption = true ]
        then
                recycle
                echo "removed '$file' to the Recycle Bin"
        fi
}


### Assigning the values of flename, absolute path  and inode to variable
### name, absolute_path and inode before sending it to recyclebin folder

recycle() {

        # If no errors mv the file to the recyclebin folder and add to .restore.info file.

    if [ $file != "Error" ] ; then
        name=$(basename ${file})                                                   #bcz file can be entered with full path
        path_cropped=$(readlink -e ${i} | cut -d"/" -f6-)
        path=$(dirname $(readlink -e ${i} | cut -d"/" -f6-))
        absolute_path="${HOME}/${path_cropped}"
        inode=$(stat -c '%i' ${file})
        filename=$name"_"$inode
        echo $newfilename:$fixedPath >> $HOME/.restore.info
        mv $file $recyclepath/$newfilename
    fi
}

###--------------------Starts from here after checking dir if exists or not--------------------------------------

        ###Declaring variables which further fulfills condition to act as i, v, r commands
        ###as i = iOption; v = vOption; no command = noChoice and recycle files recursively
        ### = r or R

        noChoice=true
        iOption=false
        vOption=false
        removeFolder=false

        while getopts ivrRvi opt
        do
                case $opt in
                        iv)
                                iOption=true
                                vOption=true
                                noChoice=false
                                break;;

                        vi)
                                iOption=true
                                vOption=true
                                noChoice=false
                                break;;

                        i)
                                iOption=true
                                noChoice=false
                                break;;

                        v)                                                                                                                     
                                vOption=true
                                noChoice=false
                                break;;

                        r)
                                removeFolder=true
                                break;;

                        R)
                                removeFolder=true
                                break;;
                esac
        done
        shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

### CAlling the test function to test all the mentioned conditioned inside the test function
        test



--------------------------------------------------------------------------
``` ```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
**Solved code** 

``` ```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````



#!bin/bash

### 2. creating directory ~/recyclebin in home if not present

if [[ ! -d $HOME/recyclebin ]]
then
        mkdir $HOME/recyclebin
        #touch $HOME/.restore.info
fi


### Creating .restore.info file if file is not yet present in
### home directory

if [ -d $HOME/recyclebin ] && [ ! -e $HOME/.restore.info ]
then
        touch $HOME/.restore.info
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "recycle: missing operand"
        exit 1
fi

### 4. Test Conditions to check

testCondition() {
        for arg in "$@"
                do

                file=$arg

                ###File Does Not Exist Error
                if [ ! -e "$file" ]
                then
                        echo "recycle: Cannot delete $file: No such file exists"
                        file="Error"
                        exit 2

                ###Directory Name provided
                elif [ -d $file ]
                then
                        echo "recycle: Cannot delete $file : Is a directory."
                        file="Error"
                        exit 3

                ###cannot delete any argument with recycle in it
                elif [[ "${file}" =~ .*"recycle".* ]]
                then
                        echo "recycle: Attempting to delete – operation aborted"
                        file="Error"
                        exit 4
                fi

                processRequest $file
                done
}

processRequest(){

        if [[ "$noChoice" = true ]]
        then
                recycle $file

        elif [ "$iOption" = true ] && [ "$vOption" = true ]
        then
                echo "recycle: remove file '$file' ? [y/n] " 
                read response

                case $response in
                        [yY]*)
                                recycle $file
                                echo "recycle: '$file' is removed";;
                        *)
                                continue ;;
                esac
        elif [ "$iOption" = true ]
        then
                read -p "recycle: remove file '$file' ? [y/n] " response

                case $response in
                        [yY]*)
                                recycle $file
                                echo "recycle: '$file' is removed";;
                        *)
                                continue ;;
                esac

        elif [ "$vOption" = true ]
        then
                recycle $file
                echo "removed '$file' to the Recycle Bin"
        fi
}


### Assigning the values of flename, absolute path  and inode to variable
### name, absolute_path and inode before sending it to recyclebin folder

recycle() {

        # If no errors mv the file to the recyclebin folder and add to .restore.info file.

    if [[ ! $file == "Error" ]]
    then
        name=$(basename $file)                                                   #bcz file can be entered with full path
        path_cropped=$(readlink -e $file | cut -d"/" -f6-)
        absolute_path="${HOME}/${path_cropped}"
        inode=$(stat -c '%i' $file)
        filename=$name"_"$inode
        echo $filename:$absolute_path >> $HOME/.restore.info                    # saving filename:path/to/file in .restore.info
        mv $file $HOME/recyclebin/$filename                                     # movinf file as filename_inode to recyclebin
    fi
}

recFolder() {
        for arg in $*
        do
                dirPath=$(readlink -e "$arg")
                if [ -d "$dirPath" ]                                            # check if the current argument IS a directory
                then
                        if [[ $(ls "$dirPath" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]                 #check to see if current directory is empty
                        then
                                rmdir $dirPath

                        else                                                    #if not an empty directory
                                findCurPathList=$(find $dirPath)                # to find all the subdirectories and files list inside directory
                                for file in $findCurPathList
                                do
                                        if [[ -f "$file" ]]                     #if it is a file
                                        then
                                                processRequest "$file"
                                        fi
                                done

                                #-----------------------------------------------Now in previous loop, once all the files are removed and saved in
                                                                                #recyclebinfolder and in .recycle.info file. Now delete the
                                                                                #empty subdirectories in second loop
                                for args1 in $findCurPathList
                                do
                                        if [[ -d $args1 ]]
                                        then
                                                if [[ $(ls $args1 | wc -l) -eq 0  ]]
                                                then
                                                        rmdir $args1
                                                fi
                                        fi
                                done

                                #if [[ $(ls "$arg" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]                 #check to see if current directory is empty
                                #then
                                #       rmdir $dirPath
                                #fi
                        fi
                else                                                            # if NOT a directory then this executes
                        echo "recycle: not a directory"
                fi
        done
}

###--------------------Starts from here, after checking dir if exists or not--------------------------------------

        ###Declaring variables which further fulfills condition to act as i, v, r commands
        ###as i = iOption; v = vOption; no command = noChoice and recycle files recursively
        ### = r or R

        noChoice=true
        iOption=false
        vOption=false
        removeFolder=false

        while getopts ivrR opt
        do
                case $opt in

                        i)
                                iOption=true
                                noChoice=false;;

                        v)
                                vOption=true
                                noChoice=false;;

                        r)
                                removeFolder=true;;

                        R)
                                removeFolder=true;;

                        *)
                                echo "recycle: invalid input"
                                exit 1;;
                esac
        done
        shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

        ### Now checking if -r or -R is passed as an argument and the passed in file argument
        ### is either directory or existing file to continue

        if [[ "$removeFolder" == true ]]
        then
                for arg in "$@"
                do
                        inputArg=$arg

                        if [[ -d $inputArg || -e $inputArg ]]                           # if the user pass -r request but the argument could either be
                        #a directory o a file not directory
                        then
                                argList=$(find "$inputArg")

                                recFolder "$argList"
                        else
                                echo "recycle: $inputArg does not exist!"
                        fi
                done
        else

                ### CAlling the test function to test all the mentioned conditioned inside the test function
                testCondition "$@"

        fi
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: You should almost certainly be using `for arg in "$@"` rather than `for arg in $*` — it matters intensely which you use if the file names contain white space.  The `if [ $# -eq 0 ]` test will not be executed; `$#` will be zero only if there are no names in `$*`, and the code won't enter the loop if there are no names in `$*`.  It is also generally best to avoid using the keyword `function` when defining functions.

Comment: Also, remember that `test` is a built-in command.  Writing a function `test` is treading on horribly thin ice.  I'm not sure whether that's your trouble, but it is probably best to avoid naming a function `test` to avoid any risk of confusion with the built-in.  I'm not certain it's a cause of your trouble.  I am sure it has the potential to confuse readers of your code later.

Comment: I suggest to use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your code for errors. How do you check that function `test` is not called? It will not do anything if called without arguments as you do in the last line of your script. You can add a line `set -x` after `#!/bin/bash` (or later) to make the shell print all commands before executing them.

Comment: I forgot to pass in the arguments `test $*` at the very end of the code when the test function is called in the beginning. And also I changed the name of the function test to testCondition as test being a UNX pre-defined keyword too.

Comment: @ManiPabla Please [edit] your question and show the exact code you are using instead of describing changes to the code.  Show how exactly you call your script and the expected and actual output.

Comment: Hello, i am new here. Can you tell me if I have the updated code, how can I put it here rather than adding that to my question's code part. Thank You